# How do I allow for 500.html to be used in Spring Boot only when the request was HTML first

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

What I want is given `curl localhost:8080/fail` I want it to show a JSON exception message as it is a typical API call, but if I view http://localhost:8080 from the browser I want it to show the HTML version that's stored in my templates

I presently have a general exception handler for the REST API calls

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GeneralExceptionHandler implements Ordered {

  @Override
  public int getOrder() {

    return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE; // I'm already at lowest precedence.

  }

  @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Status> handleException(@NotNull Throwable e) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        .body(StatusProto.fromThrowable(e));
  }
}
```

But I also have an HTML 500 error page in `src/main/templates/error/500.html`  I also have a 404 error page `src/main/templates/error/404.html` and that works correctly.

However, when I get a failure, it seems to use my exception handler all the time even if I am accessing the page from the browser.

I test it by adding in my controller class

```java
@Controller // I'm not a RestController
public class MyController {

  @GetMapping("/fail")
  public String fail() {

    throw new IllegalStateException("Test for 500");

  }
}
```

And requesting `/fail` but it is always giving me the JSON rather than the HTML.

Is there some other configuration I have to do?

Comment: So to understand the requirement... you need your apis to answer with the error handler when it is **not** called by a browser and the error pages if it is called by a browser?

Comment: Because if that is the case I think (need to confirm) `ExceptionHandler` has priority over the spring error pages mechanism and if you need a this specific requirement you will probably need to override some spring configurations and rely on headers to identify whether it is a browser or not.

Comment: you're correct let me clarify it more.

Comment: I think the best option you have is to make your REST endpoints under a specific path like `localhost:8080/api` with that you can use the `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method to either send the json or let spring handle the error with the pages... If i recall correcly method `handleException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex)` then get the URI and `startsWith("/api/")` if so your response status if not use this one `return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);` check if it works and let me know I will add an answer (you can do the same with headers)

Answer (score 0):

I basically had to check if it is an HTML request and route accordingly

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GeneralExceptionHandler implements Ordered {

  @Override
  public int getOrder() {
    return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
  public Object handleException(@NotNull Throwable e, @NotNull final WebRequest request) {

    final var acceptHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT);
    var isHtmlRequest = false;
    if (acceptHeader != null) {
      isHtmlRequest = Arrays.asList(acceptHeader.split(",")).contains(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE);
    }
    if (isHtmlRequest) {
      return "error/500";
    } else {
      return ResponseEntity.internalServerError()
          .body(
              StatusProto.fromThrowable(
                  io.grpc.Status.INTERNAL
                      .withDescription(e.getMessage())
                      .withCause(e)
                      .asRuntimeException()));
    }
  }
}
```

There also appears to be a bug/inconsistency in the [Chain of Resolvers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-servlet/exceptionhandlers.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers-handling) in that it states

> `null` if the exception remains unresolved, for subsequent resolvers to try, and, if the exception remains at the end, it is allowed to bubble up to the Servlet container.

But returning null instead of `error/500` gives me a 0-byte content.